# Replace '/' with '\/' in string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change a string variable `'foo / bar'` into `'foo \/ bar'` but I keep getting `'foo \\/ bar'`.  I don't want to hard code it.  How is it done?

```
> fb = 'foo / bar'
'foo / bar'
> fb.replace('/', '\\/')
'foo \\/ bar'
> fb.substr(0, fb.indexOf('/')) + '\\' + fb.substr(fb.indexOf('/'))
'foo \\/ bar'
```

Comment: try `console.log('foo / bar'.replace('/', '\\/'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `replace` (`fb.replace('/', '\\/')`) is correct (if you only want to replace the first one). It's just that whatever console you're using is showing you the string in string literal format, and in a string literal, to actually have a `\` in a string, you have to escape it (with another `\`). Your replaced string actually only has one `\` in it, it's just how the console is displaying it to you.

Gratuitous example:

```js
var fb = 'foo / bar';
fb = fb.replace('/', '\\/');
var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode(fb)
);
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

---

If you want to replace *all* `/` in the string (if there were more than one):

```
var fb = "foo / bar";
fb = fb.replace(/\//g, "\\/");
```